# Fetching hour value from a time field in current user's timezone

Tags: formula, formula-field

By using the below formula I'm trying to lock the record from editing.

**Lock_Date_Time__c** - Field which is capturing the date time when the record was locked.

```
AND(

    / ******* If the time diff is less than 1 hour *********/
    (
        ( TIMENOW() - TIMEVALUE( Lock_Date_Time__c ) ) / 60000 
    ) < 60,

    OR(
        /******* If the day is same and time diff is less than 1 hr. *******/

        DAY( ( DATEVALUE( Lock_Date_Time__c ) ) ) = DAY( TODAY() ), 

        / ********  If the day is diff by one 1 day and time diff is less than 1 hr. 
                    Ex: If the locked date time was 22nd June 11:02 PM and we are 
                    viewing the record on 23rd June 12:01 AM. In this case the time diff 
                    is still less than 1 hour but the date is changed ******** /
        ( 
            DAY( ( DATEVALUE( Lock_Date_Time__c ) ) ) - DAY( TODAY() ) = 1
            && (    HOUR( TIMEVALUE( Lock_Date_Time__c ) ) > 11 
                    && HOUR( TIMEVALUE( Lock_Date_Time__c ) ) < 12 
            )
            && MINUTE( TIMEVALUE( Lock_Date_Time__c ) ) > 1
        )
    )
)
```

The static comparison that is done in the OR condition is taking the GMT time into consideration( TIMEVALUE() converts the datetime into time in GMT timezone ). Is there any way we can make this comparison to happen in current user's timezone ?

Comment: _We have a requirement to lock the record for one hour_ : smells like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Why don't you want the locking to apply to the same "absolute time" for all users, regardless of timezone?

Comment: How we can handle the case - When day diff is 1 and the time diff is less than 1 hour ? To handle this case I think we need to add a static comparison ( last condition in the formula ), how will that work if we consider the absolute time ?

Ex: If the locked date time was 22nd June 11:02 PM and we are 
      viewing the record on 23rd June 12:01 AM. In this case the time diff 
      is still less than 1 hour but the date is changed .